# Calculate Number of months between times using countdowntimer

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am calculating time difference between two dates..

```
Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        long currentDateInMillis = currentDate.getTimeInMillis();

        //Set Event Date and time
        Calendar nextDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                        // set the month, date, year, hour, minute, second, and millisecond
        nextDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
        nextDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10); // January is 0, Feb is 1, etc.
        nextDate.set(Calendar.DATE, 27);
        nextDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        nextDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        nextDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        nextDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        long nextDateInMillis = nextDate.getTimeInMillis();

        timeDiff = nextDateInMillis - currentDateInMillis;



    timer = new CountDownTimer(timeDiff, 1000) 
            {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
                {
                    int totalSeconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);

                    int daysText     = (int) (totalSeconds / 86400);
                    int hoursText    = (int) ((totalSeconds % 86400) / 3600);
                    int minutesText  = (int) (((totalSeconds % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
                    //int secondsText = (int) (((totalSeconds % 86400) % 3600) % 60);

                    minutes.setText(String.valueOf(minutesText));
                    hours.setText(String.valueOf(hoursText));
                    days.setText(String.valueOf(daysText));
                }

                public void onFinish() 
                {

                }
            };
            timer.start();
```

The above works good but it gives days and hours and seconds. I want it to tell me the months too. But the problem is each month has diff number of days So How can i find number of months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)?

For example:

```
public class DateTimeUtils {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      DateTimeUtils obj = new DateTimeUtils();
      SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = 
               new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

      try {

        Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse("10/10/2013 11:30:10");
        Date date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse("13/11/2014 20:35:55");

        obj.printDifference(date1, date2);  

      } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }

    public void printDifference(Date startDate, Date endDate){

      Interval interval = 
               new Interval(startDate.getTime(), endDate.getTime());
      Period period = interval.toPeriod();

          System.out.printf(
           "%d years, %d months, %d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds%n", 
           period.getYears(), period.getMonths(), period.getDays(),
           period.getHours(), period.getMinutes(), period.getSeconds());

    }
}
```

Just input two times and the output would be something like:

```
a years, b months, c days, d hours etc...
```

Comment: i am making a count down timer unfortunately :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say LotusUNSW's answer had pretty much what you needed. So, I'll just add a little more info... You just need to get the current time (or pass it in since you had it), take the number of milliseconds for the count down time, add them together for a target time, and then find the time interval between your current time and target time using [Interval](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html).

Using [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) as LotusUNSW was...

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
{
    long currentTime = DateTimeUtils.currentTimeMillis();
    Period period = new Interval(currentTime, currentTime + 
        millisUntilFinished).toPeriod(PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime());
    System.out.printf("%d years, %d months, %d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds%n", 
        period.getYears(), period.getMonths(), period.getDays(),
        period.getHours(), period.getMinutes(), period.getSeconds());   
}
```

For the date you have there, the output from that looks like this: `0 years, 0 months, 10 days, 14 hours, 6 minutes, 29 seconds`

You can find different `PeriodType` options [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/PeriodType.html). If you would prefer to have just the total of one type of unit, there are PeriodTypes for that, such as `PeriodType.months()` if you want the total time in months.